# Anime or manga about a guy who can see voices as colors

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

There is an anime/manga about a guy who can see people's voices as colors. He saves a child from some sort of monster made from the child's own fears. He then is hired and taught how to defeat these monsters.

I only got to read/watch a little of it.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is [Catharsis](https://meltingpotsandothercalamities.wordpress.com/2017/08/11/most-beautiful-webtoons-by-genre-fantasy/)

> Catharsis has a beautiful, dream like quality about it…which is only fitting, as the characters (and the Catharsis agency) deal with nightmares. This has a very soft, subtle look, which can turn horrifying in a heartbeat when dealing with the nightmarish creatures known as Timorem, beings that latch onto fear. Their design is creepy, but really unique and creative; they are genuinely rather frightening looking. The main character, Leon, has synesthesia, making him able to see people’s voices as colors. This causes some of the best coloring in the entire series, as voices and colors blend together.

You can find it [here.](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/catharsis/list?title_no=396&webtoon-platform-redirect=true)